# Merge one-line texts into a data-frame with basic ubuntu shell commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text

I have let's say two files `Input1.txt` and `Input2.txt`. Each of them is a text file containing a single line of 5 numbers separated by a tab.

For instance `Input1.txt` is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

and `Input2.txt` is

```
6 7 8 9 10
```

The output that I desire is `Output.txt` :

```
Input1 1 2 3 4 5
Input2 6 7 8 9 10
```

So I want to merge the files in a table with an extra first column containing the names of the original files. Obviously I have more than 2 files (actually 1000) and I would like to make it with a for loop. You can assume that all my files are named as Input*.txt with * between 1 and 1000 and that they are all in the same directory.

I know how to do it with R, but I would like to make it with a basic line of commands in the ubuntu shell. Is it feasible ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The format of the input files is not fully clear to me. Do `Input1.txt` and `Input2.txt` contain a single line each, i.e. `1 2 3 4 5` or `6 2 8 9 10` respectively? How do you specify your 1000 input files? Can you use a wildcard, e.g. `Input*.txt` or do you want to process all files in the current directory and maybe in all subdirectories?

Comment: Yes that's exactly this format. You can indeed use Input*.txt with * between 1 and 1000. That being said, they are also all in the same directory.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the line in `Input1.txt`, `Input2.txt`, etc. is terminated with a newline character, you can use

```
for i in Input*.txt
do
    printf "%s " "$i"
    cat "$i"
done > Output.txt
```

The result is

```
Input1.txt 1 2 3 4 5
Input2.txt 6 7 8 9 10
```

If you want to get `Input1` etc. without `.txt` you can use

```
    printf "%s " "${i%.txt}"
```